# How to get Update-Notifications when using Gnome Fallback on Ubuntu Precise Pangolin?

Tags: updates, update-manager, gnome-classic, notification, notification-area

one of my friends is using Gnome Fallback ( [activated by installing gnome-panel](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed) ). Problem is that he does not get notifications about updates anymore. Well, we could set up automatic updates in the background, but this is not what we want.

Is there a way to get a notification about available updates in the notification-area?

Thanks!

Comment: I just found this [link](http://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-restore-automatic-update-notification-icon-in-ubuntu-9-04.html) for Ubuntu Jaunty. Not sure if this trick still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your terminal and type as `sudo apt-get install gnonf-editor` then open it by typing as `gconf-editor` .

Then navigate to `/` `apps` ->  `update-notifier` 
Then 
[image]

Ok This for you in dconf-editor

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What do the number mean?

Comment: Those are I think for a week checking .

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 (I have tried two different installations) the entry in dconf-editor is not under 'apps', but I found it on both machines under *com -> ubuntu -> update-notifier* . (Is your screen from Precise Pangolin?) I noticed that 'release-check-time' was on both machines set to an arbitrarily high integer value. One of them was: 1351805925. I do not really understand why the update-notifier maintains different thresholds for the notification intervals than the settings for the package sources (where I can select the repositories). Anyway, I'll have to see if this solves my problem.

Comment: mine was gconf-editor. place those as i have placed .

Comment: Watched it over some days and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got one more answer for you . That is adding the update notifier to startup application list.

1 Open start up application .
2 Click at ADD
3 Open /usr/bin/ location through Browse button
4 Then choose update-notifier from the list .

Look at the image for more information . Hope that helps .[image]